# Selecting contacts from phone-book by mime type

Tags: android, android-contacts, contentobserver

I am trying to fetch contacts from phone by `MIME-TYPE`, so i can select contacts that has the type:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
```

Here is the method i use:

```
public static ArrayList<Contact> fetchContactsFromPhone(@NonNull Context context) {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;

    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));

            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
            long hasPhoneNumber = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        PhoneCONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = " + contact_id + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + "'"+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'"
                        , null, null);


                if (phoneCursor != null) {
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        Contact contact = new Contact();

                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[()\\-\\s]", "").trim();

                        contact.setName(name);
                        contact.setPhoneNum(phoneNumber);

                        contacts.add(contact);
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    //return data
    return contacts;
}
```

The problem is this query, return **ZERO** contacts.

Any Idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the table `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` which contains **only** Data rows with `MIMETYPE` = `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`.
But you're asking for rows with MIMETYPE `CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` so you're getting an empty cursor.

It's an easy fix to your existing code, but even when fixed, you're code is very slow, it'll run a query per contact on the device, this can easily be hundreds or even thousands of queries. If you just need to get the name+number of all contacts, try the following code (one query to get all):

```
ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

// Make sure you import Phone from ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone

String[] projection = { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String number = cur.getString(2);

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + number);

    Contact contact = new Contact();

    contact.setName(name);
    contact.setPhoneNum(number);
    contacts.add(contact);
}

if (cur != null) {
    cur.close();
}
```

Note that similar to your code, this code might create multiple `Contact` objects for each contact, in case a contact has more then one phone.
If you want only one `Contact` object per contact, you need to modify your `Contact` object to contain a list of phones, and change the `ArrayList<Contact>` to `HashMap<Long, Contact>` so you can add a phone to an existing object instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I am accepting you answer as it solves the issue of getting `zero` results plus enhancing performance, Thanks. however the condition i use of filtering by MIME-TYPE is because I am trying to fetch contacts that does not belong to any account [WhatsApp account for ex] as this results in fetching duplicate contacts for same number but with different formats! Also my app add contacts like WhatsApp so in fetching I am getting many duplicate contacts from many accounts! do you have any idea of how to overcome this?

Comment: As I mentioned below the code in my answer, filtering by account won't help you, as contacts that have more then one number will be duplicated even when selecting from a single account (google for example). You need to change your `ArrayList` to `HashMap`, where the key is `CONTACT_ID`, and put multiple numbers belonging to the same contact within a single `Contact` object

Comment: Yes, you are correct!, Thanks a lot for your help :)